# Change value of leaf in NLTK

Tags: python, tree, nlp, nltk

I want to change the value of a leaf in a parsed tree object in NLTK. I use the following code.

```
t = Tree(line)
chomsky_normal_form(t, horzMarkov=2, vertMarkov=1, childChar = "|", parentChar = "^")
print t

for leaf in t.leaves():
    if leaf==k[0][1]:
        leaf = "newValue"
 print t
```

As it is now the two 'print t' gives the exact same output of the tree. I thought it was possible to set a value to a leaf in this way but it seems I was wrong. 
How should I do to update the value of the leaf? 
The class of each leaf is str. So it is possible to change them but it doesn't seem update to update the object in the tree.

Comment: I guess that is because str objects are ummutable in Python. But is there any way I could do to change it?

Comment: This is not because strings are immutable, but because `=` is assignment to the *name* (variable) `leaf`, not its contents.

Comment: Well, Python is not my first language. Could you pleas explain how to change it so the content changes?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with NLTK APIs to help you much further, but you'll never be able to do this using the `leaves` method. It doesn't return the required information.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `treepositions('leaves')` ([docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree.treepositions)) to get the position of the leaves in the tree and change it directly in your tree.

```
t = Tree(line)
chomsky_normal_form(t, horzMarkov=2, vertMarkov=1, childChar = "|", parentChar = "^")

for leafPos in t.treepositions('leaves'):
    if t[leafPos] == k[0][1]:
        t[leafPos] = "newValue"
 print t
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have previous experience with Tree, and the class documentation didn't suggest an obvious method for altering the leaves. But, looking at the [source](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tree-pysrc.html#Tree.leaves) for the leaves method, it appears to just be a dressed-up form of list. I fiddled with it in the console for a minute, and I think this might get you moving in the right direction:

```
>>> t = Tree("(s (dp (d the) (np dog)) (vp (v chased) (dp (d the) (np cat))))")
>>> t.leaves()
['the', 'dog', 'chased', 'the', 'cat']
>>> t[0][0][0] = "newValue"
>>> t.leaves()
['newValue', 'dog', 'chased', 'the', 'cat']
```

Comment: Thanks. It moved me in the right direction (the one I was initially trying to avoid). It seems like the way you can change this is by accessing the tree object by directly referring to its nodes. And that can´t be done by the leaves() method. I made a routine to traverse the treee and search for the appropriate leaaf.